# Will an app compiled with iOS 8.2 SDK and RoboVM work on iOS 9?

Tags: xcode, ios8, libgdx, ios9, robovm

I've a libGDX game in AppStore compiled with ios 8.2 SDK, XCode 6.2 and RoboVM plugin 1.6 for Android Studio. Will it work on iOS 9?

Comment: Why not try and install it on iOS 9 and see if it does?

Comment: My device is currently running on iOS 8.4. As per Apple, once you upgrade it to iOS 9,  it can't be reverted back. This is my primary device and I don't want to break it.

Comment: iOS updates generally do not break older apps. But iOS 7 messed up sound in a lot of apps and left it up to their developers to fix them. So as long as there are no surprises like that, it *should* work.